# Is there a maximum number that you can change the style property of an html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I am using [ElectronJS](https://electronjs.org/) to create an application that generates an STL file from a grayscale image. In such I have some nested loops that go through every other pixel to write the coordinates for each facet to a file. I am trying to implement a progress bar for the process (processing a 4k image can take up to 30 min) by updating the width property of a div. However, even though I set the new width in the loop, it seems as though the width does not update until after the loops have finished. Am I updating the style too quickly?

Since I do not include the rest of the js below, the select file button lets the user select a file from their file system (that is an image). The convert button uses that file path and [Opencv](https://opencv.org/) to find the "heights" of the pixels of the image (which is read as grayscale) and to write to an stl file the facets that would come about from connecting those "heights".

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>File Select</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/convert.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button id="select-file-button" onclick="selectFile()">Select File</button>
      <p id="filename"></p>
      <div id="progress-bar" style="--width: 2%"></div>
      <button id="test" onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
      <!-- Excluded from page -->
      <img id="img-for-analysis" src=""/>
      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/convert.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@font-face {font-family: "Orkney Light"; src: url('./fonts/orkney/Orkney\ Light.ttf')}
@font-face {font-family: "Orkney Medium"; src: url('./fonts/orkney/Orkney\ Medium.ttf')}
@font-face {font-family: "Orkney Bold"; src: url('./fonts/orkney/Orkney\ Bold.ttf')}

body {
   margin: 0;  
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#progress-bar {
   width: 50vw;
   height: 5vh;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 5vw;
   position: relative
}
#progress-bar::before {
   content: "";
   width: calc(var(--width, 0) * 1%);
   position: absolute;
   left: 1vw;
   top: 1vh;
   bottom: 1vh;
   min-width: 0.1vw;
   max-width: calc(100% - 2vw);
   background-color: red;
   border-radius: 10000vw;
}
#img-for-analysis {
   margin-top: 100vh;
   opacity: 0;
   position: fixed;
}
```

And here is the section of the js file linked where the conversion process occurs, including the code for the progress bar:

```
/*
 * Progress bar
 */
const progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')

/**
 * Returns the current width of the progress bar
 */
function getProgressBarWidth() {
  const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(progressBar)
  const width = parseFloat(computedStyle.getPropertyValue('--width')) || 0
  return width
}

/**
 * Update the progress bar with the given value
 * @param {number} newWidth - A positive number meant to be the new percent of the progress bar
 */
function updateProgressBar (newWidth) {
  progressBar.style.setProperty('--width', newWidth * 100)
}


/*
 * Convert
 */

/**
 * Writes the generic beginning of a facet to the given stream
 * @param {fs write stream} stream 
 */
function writeFacetBeginning (stream) {
  stream.write("facet normal 0 0 0" + "\n" + "outer loop" + "\n")
}

/**
 * Writes the generic beginning of a caet to the given stream
 * @param {fs write stream} stream 
 */
function writeFacetEnd (stream) {
  stream.write("endloop" + "\n" + "endfacet" + "\n")
}

/**
 * Coverts the already selected file to an stl file
 */
function convert() {
  // Not converting if there is no file selected
  if(filePath == null) {
    return
  }


  // Making the mat
  let src = cv.imread('img-for-analysis', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

  // Variable to hold the pixel values of the image
  let pixelValues = [...Array(src.rows)].map(e => Array(src.cols).fill(null))
  //Storing the values of the pixels in the array
  for(let i = 0; i < src.rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < src.cols; j++) {
      pixelValues[i][j] = parseInt(src.ucharAt(i, j * src.channels()))
    }
  }

  // Creating the read stream
  let stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName.split('.')[0] + '.stl', {flags: 'w'})

  // Settings
  let scale = 1/255

  // Status
  let maxProgress = (src.rows * src.cols)  // Every pixel + initial triangles for sides
  let currentProgress = 0

  stream.write("solid pic" + "\n")

    /*
    * Iterating through every other pixel to generate the facets of the top face
    *
    *                * -- * -- *
    *                |  \ | /  |
    *                * -- * -- *
    *                |  / | \  |
    *                * -- * -- *
    *
    */

    for (let row = 1; row < src.rows; row+=2)
    {
        for (let col = 1; col < src.cols; col+=2)
        {
            /*
            *
            * Creating facets w/ clockwise vertexes
            *
            * facet normal n1 n2 n3
            *   outer loop
            *     vertex x y z
            *     vertex x y z
            *     vertex x y z
            *   "\n"oop
            * endfacets
            */

            /* Top-Left
                *--*
                 \ |
                   *
            */
            writeFacetBeginning(stream);
          stream.write("vertex " + row + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row][col] * scale + "\n")
            stream.write("vertex " + (row-1) + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[(row-1)][col] * scale + "\n")
            stream.write("vertex " + (row-1) + " " +(col-1)+ " " + pixelValues[row-1][col-1] * scale + "\n")
            writeFacetEnd(stream);

            /* Top-Left
                *
                | \
                *--*
            */
            writeFacetBeginning(stream);
            stream.write("vertex " + row + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row][col] * scale + "\n")
            stream.write("vertex " + (row-1) + " " +(col-1)+ " " + pixelValues[(row-1)][col - 1] * scale + "\n")
            stream.write("vertex " + row + " " +(col-1)+ " " + pixelValues[row][col-1] * scale + "\n")
            writeFacetEnd(stream);

            /* Top-Right
                *--*
                | /
                *
            */
            if (col+1 < src.cols) //Is this pixel not on the last column
            {
                writeFacetBeginning(stream);
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row][col] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " + (row-1) + " " +(col+1)+ " " + pixelValues[(row-1)][col + 1] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " + (row-1) + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[(row-1)][col] * scale + "\n")
                writeFacetEnd(stream);

                /* Top-Right
                       *
                     / |
                    *--*
                */
                writeFacetBeginning(stream);
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row][col] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " +(col+1)+ " " + pixelValues[row][col + 1] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " + (row-1) + " " +(col+1)+ " " + pixelValues[(row-1)][col + 1] * scale + "\n")
                writeFacetEnd(stream);
            }

            if (row + 1 < src.rows) //Is this pixel not on the last row?
            {
                /* Bottom-Left
                       *
                     / |
                    *--*
                */
                writeFacetBeginning(stream);
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row][col] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " +(row+1)+ " " +(col-1)+ " " + pixelValues[row + 1][col - 1] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " +(row+1)+ " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row + 1][col] * scale + "\n")
                writeFacetEnd(stream);

                /* Bottom-Left
                    *--*
                    | /
                    *
                */
                writeFacetBeginning(stream);
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row][col] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " +(col-1)+ " " + pixelValues[row][col - 1] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " +(row+1)+ " " +(col-1)+ " " + pixelValues[row + 1][col - 1] * scale + "\n")
                writeFacetEnd(stream);
            }

            if (row + 1 < src.rows &&(col+1)< src.cols)
            {
                /* Bottom-Right
                    *
                    | \
                    *--*
                */
                writeFacetBeginning(stream);
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row][col] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " +(row+1)+ " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row + 1][col] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " +(row+1)+ " " +(col+1)+ " " + pixelValues[row + 1][col + 1] * scale + "\n")
                writeFacetEnd(stream);

                /* Bottom-Right
                    *--*
                     \ |
                       *
                */
                writeFacetBeginning(stream);
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " + col + " " + pixelValues[row][col] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " +(row+1)+ " " +(col+1)+ " " + pixelValues[row + 1][col + 1] * scale + "\n")
                stream.write("vertex " + row + " " +(col+1)+ " " + pixelValues[row][col + 1] * scale + "\n")
                writeFacetEnd(stream);
            }

            currentProgress += 4
        }
        updateProgressBar(currentProgress/maxProgress)
    }
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Browsers have only a single thread for executing JS and rendering the view. Changes to the DOM are rendered to the view after all the JS has been executed, hence only the last change can become visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser doesn't render the changes until your current execution cycle ends. So even though you update the width of the element, browser will wait for the execution cycle to render the changes, which will occur only after your whole loop is completed.

You can implement 2 different types of solutions here

#### Use requestAnimationFrame between loops

`requestAnimationFrame` executes the callback before rendering next frame, after rendering the current frame.

```
    function processRow(row = 1) {
      for (let col = 1; col < src.cols; col+=2) {
        // Your code
        currentProgress += 4;
      }
      updateProgressBar(currentProgress/maxProgress);
      if (row < src.rows) {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => processRow(row + 2));
      }
    }
```

#### Use [WebWorker](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading)

As you are not depending on DOM or making any changes to DOM for processing the image, move the whole computation part to WebWorker and post message to main thread whenever you complete a loop.

In main thread you can listen to messages from WebWorker and update the progress bar accordingly